# INNER JOIN returns unwanted matches, SEMI JOIN returns expected output, but missing columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm facing this problem for a while now, hope someone could help me solve it.

I have two data frames.

The first one contains data about the calls each customer made:

```
 Calls <- structure(list(OpenUser = c(55555, 33333, 22222, 44444, 22222, 
55555), OpenFirstName = c("Shir", "Yael", "Yair", "Roni", "Yair", 
"Shir"), OpenLastName = c("Shiran", "Eilon", "Yaron", "Ron", 
"Yaron", "Shiran"), CustomerID = c(836, 1070, 1390, 2970, 3646, 
3646), CRMEventStartDate = structure(c(1441065600, 1441065600, 
1431129600, 1435881600, 1417392000, 1441497600), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), NumOfOptions = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), groups = structure(list(OpenUser = c(22222, 
22222, 33333, 44444, 55555, 55555), OpenFirstName = c("Yair", 
"Yair", "Yael", "Roni", "Shir", "Shir"), OpenLastName = c("Yaron", 
"Yaron", "Eilon", "Ron", "Shiran", "Shiran"), CustomerID = c(1390, 
3646, 1070, 2970, 836, 3646), .rows = list(3L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 
    6L)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), .drop = TRUE))
```

The second contains data of the campaigns offered to each customer, and the response:

```
Response <- structure(list(CampaignStrategyID = c(512345, 512345, 512345, 
121212, 512345, 121212), CustomerID = c(836, 1070, 1390, 2970, 
3479, 3646), ResponseDate = structure(c(1441065600, 1441065600, 
1431129600, 1435881600, 1420502400, 1417392000), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), ResponseCode = c(1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I have to present for **each** call of the customer, what was the **actual** campaign offered, and what was their response.

INNER JOIN by CustomerID results undesired matches (not only the **actual** campaign offered)

SEMI JOIN results the desired matches (I think), but without the desired columns from the second data frame (CampaignStrategyID & ResponseCode). I did not manage to add this columns after the SEMI JOIN was done.

Hope someone could help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi David! I've added an answer below, based on what I think you are looking for. If I am incorrect, and you are able to provide the output you expect to get, then I may be able to adjust my answer to suit your desired outcome.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE 2019-03-03**

This is updated with the new data provided. To troubleshoot, I first filter the example data to the documented problem case, `CustomerID` 7033.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

Calls <- tibble(
  OpenUser = c(55555, 33333, 22222, 44444, 22222, 55555, 55555, 11111, 11111,
               44444, 44444, 11111, 44444, 44444, 33333, 44444, 11111, 33333,
               44444, 22222),
  OpenFirstName = c("Shir", "Yael", "Yair", "Roni", "Yair", "Shir", "Shir",
                    "Sigal", "Sigal", "Roni", "Roni", "Sigal", "Roni", "Roni",
                    "Yael", "Roni", "Sigal", "Yael", "Roni", "Yair"),
  OpenLastName = c("Shiran", "Eilon", "Yaron", "Ron", "Yaron", "Shiran",
                   "Shiran", "segal", "segal", "Ron", "Ron", "segal", "Ron",
                   "Ron", "Eilon", "Ron", "segal", "Eilon", "Ron", "Yaron"),
  CustomerID = c(836, 1070, 1390, 2970, 3646, 3646, 4542, 7033, 7033, 8838,
                 8838, 9040, 9040, 9973, 9973, 17472, 17472, 20409, 21626,
                 21632),
  CRMEventStartDate = ymd(c("2015-09-01", "2015-09-01", "2015-05-09",
                            "2015-07-03", "2014-12-01", "2015-09-06",
                            "2015-07-01", "2015-05-02", "2015-07-03",
                            "2015-06-04", "2015-07-08", "2015-03-01",
                            "2015-05-06", "2015-05-31", "2015-08-09",
                            "2015-04-01", "2015-08-02", "2015-04-01",
                            "2015-04-04", "2015-02-01")),
  NumOfOptions = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L,
                   3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L)
)

Response <- tibble(
  CampaignStrategyID = c(512345, 512345, 512345, 121212, 512345, 121212, 516345,
                         516345, 121212, 512345, 121212, 512345, 121212, 512345,
                         516345, 512345, 512345, 512345, 121212, 516345, 512345,
                         512345, 516345, 512345, 516345, 512345, 512345, 121212,
                         121212, 512345, 121212, 512345, 516345, 516345, 512345,
                         121212, 121212, 121212, 512345, 512345, 121212, 516345,
                         121212, 121212, 516345, 516345, 512345, 121212, 121212,
                         121212),
  CustomerID = c(836, 1070, 1390, 2970, 3479, 3646, 3646, 4278, 4542, 7033,
                 7033, 8838, 8838, 9040, 9040, 9973, 9973, 17472, 17472, 20409,
                 21626, 21632, 22414, 24005, 24005, 26432, 26432, 28101, 28101,
                 31536, 31536, 31598, 31598, 32979, 32979, 35099, 37471, 37471,
                 38832, 38832, 39778, 40318, 40318, 46547, 48885, 48885, 49523,
                 49585, 55134, 56878),
  ResponseDate = ymd(c("2015-09-01", "2015-09-01", "2015-05-09", "2015-07-03",
                       "2015-01-06", "2014-12-01", "2015-09-06", "2015-01-02",
                       "2015-07-01", "2015-05-02", "2015-07-03", "2015-06-04",
                       "2015-07-08", "2015-03-01", "2015-05-06", "2015-05-31",
                       "2015-08-09", "2015-04-01", "2015-08-02", "2015-04-01",
                       "2015-04-04", "2015-02-01", "2015-01-31", "2015-05-08",
                       "2015-06-08", "2015-02-08", "2015-05-09", "2015-01-08",
                       "2015-08-04", "2015-06-06", "2015-06-09", "2015-05-05",
                       "2015-05-08", "2015-02-04", "2015-09-01", "2014-12-02",
                       "2014-12-04", "2015-07-02", "2015-05-08", "2015-09-01",
                       "2015-07-03", "2015-04-03", "2015-06-02", "2014-12-09",
                       "2015-01-03", "2015-09-09", "2015-06-04", "2015-08-06",
                       "2015-06-09", "2015-02-06")),
  ResponseCode = c(1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 4, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 4,
                   1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1,
                   3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 1, 1, 3, 2)
)

test_calls <- filter(Calls, CustomerID == 7033)
test_calls
#> # A tibble: 2 x 6
#>   OpenUser OpenFirstName OpenLastName CustomerID CRMEventStartDa…
#>      <dbl> <chr>         <chr>             <dbl> <date>          
#> 1    11111 Sigal         segal              7033 2015-05-02      
#> 2    11111 Sigal         segal              7033 2015-07-03      
#> # … with 1 more variable: NumOfOptions <int>

test_response <- filter(Response, CustomerID == 7033)
test_response
#> # A tibble: 2 x 4
#>   CampaignStrategyID CustomerID ResponseDate ResponseCode
#>                <dbl>      <dbl> <date>              <dbl>
#> 1             512345       7033 2015-05-02              1
#> 2             121212       7033 2015-07-03              3
```

Using the `test_calls` and `test_response` data, I am able to reproduce the issue:

```r
inner_join(test_calls, test_response, by = "CustomerID")
#> # A tibble: 4 x 9
#>   OpenUser OpenFirstName OpenLastName CustomerID CRMEventStartDa…
#>      <dbl> <chr>         <chr>             <dbl> <date>          
#> 1    11111 Sigal         segal              7033 2015-05-02      
#> 2    11111 Sigal         segal              7033 2015-05-02      
#> 3    11111 Sigal         segal              7033 2015-07-03      
#> 4    11111 Sigal         segal              7033 2015-07-03      
#> # … with 4 more variables: NumOfOptions <int>, CampaignStrategyID <dbl>,
#> #   ResponseDate <date>, ResponseCode <dbl>
```

Now I can see that this is happening due to the way the matching is happening. Because we're matching only on `CustomerID`, all matching rows in `Calls` where there is a corresponding row in `Response`, so you get all combinations of the 2 rows in `Calls` x the 2 rows in `Response` (resulting in the 4 rows).

To correct this, we can also match on the date variables (`CRMEventStartDate` and `ResponseDate`):

```r
inner_join(test_calls, test_response,
           by = c("CustomerID", "CRMEventStartDate" = "ResponseDate"))
#> # A tibble: 2 x 8
#>   OpenUser OpenFirstName OpenLastName CustomerID CRMEventStartDa…
#>      <dbl> <chr>         <chr>             <dbl> <date>          
#> 1    11111 Sigal         segal              7033 2015-05-02      
#> 2    11111 Sigal         segal              7033 2015-07-03      
#> # … with 3 more variables: NumOfOptions <int>, CampaignStrategyID <dbl>,
#> #   ResponseCode <dbl>
```

This results in the expected 2 rows, with the response matched by the `CustomerID` and the date of the event.

---

**Original Post**

I think the `inner_join` should give you what you want. The `inner_join` is returning all columns from `Calls` and `Response`, but only rows that have the matching variable (`CustomerID`) in both. So, for example, `CustomerID` 3749 is not present in the `Calls` data, so there is no row for them in the joined data. Conversely, `CustomerID` 3646 has two rows in the `Calls` data, so they have 2 rows in the joined data.

```r
library(tidyverse)

Calls <- structure(list(OpenUser = c(55555, 33333, 22222, 44444, 22222, 55555),
                        OpenFirstName = c("Shir", "Yael", "Yair", "Roni", "Yair", "Shir"),
                        OpenLastName = c("Shiran", "Eilon", "Yaron", "Ron", "Yaron", "Shiran"),
                        CustomerID = c(836, 1070, 1390, 2970, 3646, 3646),
                        CRMEventStartDate = structure(c(1441065600, 1441065600, 1431129600, 1435881600, 1417392000, 1441497600),
                                                      class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"),
                        NumOfOptions = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L)),
                   row.names = c(NA, -6L),
                   class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"),
                   groups = structure(list(OpenUser = c(22222, 22222, 33333, 44444, 55555, 55555),
                                           OpenFirstName = c("Yair", "Yair", "Yael", "Roni", "Shir", "Shir"),
                                           OpenLastName = c("Yaron", "Yaron", "Eilon", "Ron", "Shiran", "Shiran"),
                                           CustomerID = c(1390, 3646, 1070, 2970, 836, 3646),
                                           .rows = list(3L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 6L)),
                                      row.names = c(NA, -6L),
                                      class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"),
                                      .drop = TRUE))


Response <- structure(list(CampaignStrategyID = c(512345, 512345, 512345, 121212, 512345, 121212),
                           CustomerID = c(836, 1070, 1390, 2970, 3479, 3646),
                           ResponseDate = structure(c(1441065600, 1441065600, 1431129600, 1435881600, 1420502400, 1417392000),
                                                    class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"),
                           ResponseCode = c(1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1)),
                      row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

inner_join(Calls, Response)
#> Joining, by = "CustomerID"
#> # A tibble: 6 x 9
#> # Groups:   OpenUser, OpenFirstName, OpenLastName, CustomerID [6]
#>   OpenUser OpenFirstName OpenLastName CustomerID CRMEventStartDate  
#>      <dbl> <chr>         <chr>             <dbl> <dttm>             
#> 1    55555 Shir          Shiran              836 2015-09-01 00:00:00
#> 2    33333 Yael          Eilon              1070 2015-09-01 00:00:00
#> 3    22222 Yair          Yaron              1390 2015-05-09 00:00:00
#> 4    44444 Roni          Ron                2970 2015-07-03 00:00:00
#> 5    22222 Yair          Yaron              3646 2014-12-01 00:00:00
#> 6    55555 Shir          Shiran             3646 2015-09-06 00:00:00
#> # … with 4 more variables: NumOfOptions <int>, CampaignStrategyID <dbl>,
#> #   ResponseDate <dttm>, ResponseCode <dbl>
```

<sup>Created on 2019-02-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Unfortentally, as mentioned in my question, INNER JOIN returns undesired matches. As you can see in this photo: https://imgur.com/a/iE9ccYU , for example, the customerID 7033 called only twice, and only 2 campaigns were offered, but in the joined data frame this customer appears 4 times, with campaigns that were NOT offered.

Comment: @David are you able to provide data that can reproduce this example? This doesn't appear to be happening with the data you provided in the question, so it is hard to know what might be going on. If you're able to provide a reproducible example, I can look into this more closely.

Comment: @David as an additional follow-up, looking at your screenshot more closely, customer 7033 has only 2 campaign strategies (121212 and 512345). This seems to be what you are expecting? There are four rows total, but that appears to be due to multiple dates for each strategy, not additional strategies.

Comment: If you can look again at customerID 7033, in the joined data frame, for the date 2015-07-03 it appears like there were 2 campaigns offered (512345, 121212), while in the response data frame (before i joined it) the *actual* campaign offered in that particular date was only 121212. so the second row in the joined data frame is wrong. as for additional data i can provide the full data for each data frame, in the next comment. Thank you for your help. @Jake Thompson

Comment: @David since it appears that id 7033 is having an issue, perhaps providing the data just for that individual from each table would be sufficient?